# How define style in App.xaml Xamarin Forms for CustomButton?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

How I can define style in App.xaml for CustomButton?

**App.xaml**

```
 <Style x:Key="CustomButtonSmall" TargetType="CustomButton">
     <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
 </Style>
```

**MyPage.xaml**

```
<local:CustomButton Text="{i18n:Translate CreateAccountButton}"  
      Grid.Column="0" Command="{Binding CreateAccountCommand}" 
      Type="Normal" Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonSmall}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In App.xaml

Give CustomButton whole path like TargetType="Control:CustomButton"
and define Control at the top like

```
 xmlns:Control="clr-namespace:xyz" 

 <Style x:Key="CustomButtonSmall" TargetType="Control:CustomButton">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You define the style in for example Window.xaml:

```
<Window>
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="Button">
       <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
       <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then u target ur button with this:

```
 <Button Style="{StaticResource myStyle}">Buttontext</Button>
```

Comment: But my TargetType is CutomButton.class, not Button